# cannot display static content on iis7.5 (except HTML)

Tags: iis-7.5, static-content

I'm attempting to move my Server 2008 (IIS7) to a different machine running R2 (IIS7.5).

Standard IIS features are installed (including static content--re: other ServerFault postings), and the default site page (pure HTML) runs fine--but it has no CSS, included images, etc.

It would certainly appear to be related to the similar "static content" postings here on ServerFault. Under Handler Mappings, I see that CGI-exe and ISAPI-dll are disabled.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and what appeared to be my problem was:

Static file handler was mapped to "`DefaultDocumentModule`" **ONLY**, after editing and setting its module to "`StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule`" every thing worked like a charm.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2196177

Comment: I like this, thanks. My particular situation was not related to this (I can't even remember what fixed it), but the fact that you encountered it is significant. I'll add it to my Things I Need To Be Aware Of...
   Michael